# How can I use jQuery to auto-generate a menu/contents based on the headings?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

In a basic XHTML document which contains some information, I'd like to have a "quick-jump" type menu of sections to be able to go to the relevant section quickly.

This is a static XHTML document, so I want all the dynamic stuff done by the browser, not the server.  I figured jQuery was the way to go.

I've looked at the jQuery UI stuff and accordion is the closest thing I can find, but I don't want the sections to collapse away - I want all the content showing and just a floating contents/menu.

From this:

```
<h2>Section 1</h2>
<p>Some information</p>
<h2>Section 2</h2>
<p>More great info</p>
```

I'd like to produce something like:

```
<ul id="menu">
  <li><a href="#section1">First section</a></li>
  <li><a href="#section2">Another section</a></li>
</ul>
<a name="section1"><h2>First section</h2></a>
<p>Some information</p>
<a name="section2"><h2>Another section</h2></a>
<p>More great info</p>
```

I don't mind wrapping each individual section in a div with a class or similar, but would like the process as automated as possible, so I only need to change the actual content when I amend the document.

Any ideas?

Thanks, F.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to just be able to call a function to automatically create the wrappers you could do something like this:

```
<ul id="menu"></ul>
<div id="sectionInfo"></div>

function addSection(name, anchor, info) {
   $("#menu").append("<li><a href='" + anchor+ "'>" + name + "</a></li>");
   $("#sectionInfo").append("<a name='" + anchor + "'><h2>" + name + "</h2></a><p>" + info + "</p>");
}
```

The HTML defines the containers for the sections, then the function itself adds the content with the wrappers you want. This would work well for simple text but if your section information has HTML in it as well it could get a bit messy. In that case, you might want to look into storing sections and their info in a database.

Usage:

```
addSection("First section", "section1", "Some information with great content");
```

**Edit**

You could then extend this to traverse the document when it's loaded to auto call this "addSection" function.

You'll need to define your sections with a more rigid structure so it's easier to traverse. I'd suggest something like this:

```
<ul id="menu"></ul>
<div id="content"></div>

<div id='sections' style='display:none;'>
    <div>
        <h2>Section 1</h2>
        <p>Some information</p>
    </div>
    <div>
        <h2>Section 2</h2>
        <p>More great info</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Then once the page is loaded, loop through the defined sections and call addSection() which transforms their content into what ever you want it to look like:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
       $("#sections div").each(function() {
            addSection($(this).find("h2").first().html(), $(this).find("p").first().html());
       });
    });

    function addSection(name, info) {
       var anchor = name.replace(/ /g,'');
       $("#menu").append("<li><a href='" + anchor+ "'>" + name + "</a></li>");
       $("#content").append("<a name='" + anchor + "'><h2>" + name + "</h2></a><p>" + info + "</p>");
    }
</script>
```

This code is untested, but the concept should work. You could make it more efficient by moving the elements instead of copying their HTML.

Comment: Thanks, but the challenge is how to get jQuery (or just plain js with DOM) to traverse the document, generating the anchor names on the sections and the links in the menu.  Your addSection() suggestion would still need me (the programmer) to know about the content of the document.

Comment: Updated my answer to show how it could automatically be called.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you are looking for a piece of JavaScript that generates content based on the results of a selector. Doesn't need anything fancy to accomplish, either:

```js
function buildSectionAnchorElement(index, heading) {
    var a = $("<a>");
    var name = "section" + index;
    $(heading).attr("name", name);
    a.attr("href", "#"+name);
    a.text($(heading).text());
    return a;
}
var headings = $("h1,h2,h3,h4");
var sections = headings.map(function(i,e) { 
    var a = buildSectionAnchorElement(i,e);
    var p = $(e).next("p");
    var li = $("<li>");
    li.append(a);
    $("#menu").append(li);
    return li;
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<ul id="menu"></ul>

<h2>something special</h2>
<p>lorem ipsum</p>

<h2>different thing</h2>
<p>dolor kismet aha bwaha</p>
```

Comment: naturally, this simple script assumes that the content is consistently formatted, doesn't do error checking, etc... It also could probably be refactored to read more cleanly, LMK if it's unclear how it works

Comment: I love the sample, the only thing missing is the CSS code to make it sticky and that follows and highlights the menu entries while scrolling the page for it to be the answer of the year for me.